# how to Set the entered values after refreshing the page in Asp.net core

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I want to show a warning that this year and season is available in the database when the repeated year and season is selected to enter information.But after showing this warning, because the page is refreshed, all the information entered in the inputs will be deleted.I want this information in the inputs not to be deleted and the user to choose another year and season

```
<form asp-controller="UserTax" asp-action="SabtKhareed" method="post">

    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center  p-2" style="background-color:#17a2b8; color:white">
        <h6>نام پروژه : <b class="text-warning">@ViewBag.proName</b></h6>

        <div class="d-flex">
            <label class="mt-2" style="margin-left:5px">سال</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="Yare" id="Yare" required  autocomplete="off">

                <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>

                <option value="1400">1400</option>
                <option value="1401">1401</option>
                <option value="1402">1402</option>
                <option value="1403">1403</option>
                <option value="1404">1404</option>
                <option value="1405">1405</option>
                <option value="1406">1406</option>
                <option value="1407">1407</option>
                <option value="1408">1408</option>
                <option value="1409">1409</option>
                <option value="1410">1410</option>

            </select>
        </div>

        <div class=" d-flex" style="margin-left:150px">
            <label label class="mt-2" style="margin-left:5px">فصل</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="FaslName" id="FaslName" required autocomplete="off">

                <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>

                <option value="بهار">بهار</option>
                <option value="تابستان">تابستان</option>
                <option value="پاییز">پاییز</option>
                <option value="زمستان">زمستان</option>
                <option value="سایر">سایر</option>

            </select>
        </div>


    </div>
    <hr />

    <div class="container-fluid" style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: hidden; direction:ltr ">

        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover  display" width="100%" style="direction:rtl;font-size:12px">
            <thead>

                <tr class="table-head-blue text-center" style="background-color: #416992; color: white; position: sticky; top: 0;">

                    <th>جزئیات</th>
                    <th>نام فروشنده</th>

         
                    <th style="font-size:12px">مبلغ خرید انجام شده</th>



                </tr>

            </thead>
            @{ var count = 0;}

            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)

            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <a class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm " style="color:white; " data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2@(count)"><i class="fa fa-info"></i></a>


                    </td>
                    <td class="text-center">@Model.ToList()[i].NameFroshande  @Model.ToList()[i].FamilyOrCoumpanyFroshande</td>


                    <td class="text-center">
                        <input class=" mt-1 text-sm text-center"   onkeyup="javascript:this.value=itpro(this.value);" name="[@i].MablaghKhreedAnjamShode" style="width:150px" required autocomplete="off" />

                    </td>

                  
                </tr>
                count++;
            }



        </table>
    </div>



    <div class=" text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success  col-4 mb-2 " type="submit">ثبت اطلاعات</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
    public IActionResult SabtKhareedView(int id)
    {
        var pro = _context.Projects.Find(id);
        ViewBag.proName = pro.projectName;
        ViewBag.proID = pro.projectID;
        var list = _context.TaminKoonande.Where(a => a.ProjectID == id && a.VazyatTaminKoonande == 1).ToList();

        return View(list);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SabtKhareed(IEnumerable<Khareed> khareed, int ProjectId, String Yare, String FaslName, int id)
    {
        var random = Convert.ToInt32(PublicClass.RandomClass.RandomString(6));
        var mainkareed = _context.MainKhareed.Where(a => a.ProjectId == ProjectId && a.Fasle == FaslName && a.Year == Yare).FirstOrDefault();

        if (mainkareed == null)
        {

            for (var i = 0; i < khareed.Count(); i++)
            {
                var taminName = _context.TaminKoonande.Find(khareed.ToList()[i].TaminKoonandeID);

                Khareed khareed1 = new Khareed();

                khareed1.MablaghKhreedAnjamShode = khareed.ToList()[i].MablaghKhreedAnjamShode;

                khareed1.ProjectId = khareed.ToList()[i].ProjectId;
                khareed1.Year = Yare;
         
                khareed1.Fasle = FaslName;
                khareed1.TaminKoonandeID = khareed.ToList()[i].TaminKoonandeID;
                khareed1.TaminKoonandeName = taminName.NameFroshande + " " + taminName.FamilyOrCoumpanyFroshande;
                khareed1.NoaeMooamele = "ریالی";

                _context.Khareed.Add(khareed1);
                _context.SaveChanges();

            }




            return RedirectToAction("KhareedListView", new { id });

        }

        TempData["Error"] = 1;

        return RedirectToAction("SabtKhareedView", new { id });
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This is the behavior of the form to load the page when submitted. You should submit your form using jquery and use a statement `event.preventDefault()` this will prevent the default behavior of form. and then you have to catch the response. and check to your criteria and work accordingly. AND in the return of Post method you have to return json object.

Comment: Please write me this as an answer.Give an example with my code

Comment: [this link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-jquery-ajax-form-submit-using-serialize-form-data-into-a-model/) should give you a hint how to do that. After you implement this search how to return json result. and use that as well.

Answer (score 0):

````
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SabtKhareed(IEnumerable<Khareed> khareed, int ProjectId, string Yare, string FaslName, int id)
{
    try
    {
        // Check if the mainkareed already exists
        var mainkareed = _context.MainKhareed.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ProjectId == ProjectId && a.Fasle == FaslName && a.Year == Yare);

        if (mainkareed == null)
        {
            // Iterate through each khareed
            foreach (var item in khareed)
            {
                // Retrieve taminName
                var taminName = _context.TaminKoonande.Find(item.TaminKoonandeID);

                // Create a new Khareed object
                var khareed1 = new Khareed
                {
                    MablaghKhreedAnjamShode = item.MablaghKhreedAnjamShode,
                    ProjectId = item.ProjectId,
                    Year = Yare,
                    Fasle = FaslName,
                    TaminKoonandeID = item.TaminKoonandeID,
                    TaminKoonandeName = taminName.NameFroshande + " " + taminName.FamilyOrCoumpanyFroshande,
                    NoaeMooamele = "ریالی"
                };

                // Add khareed1 to the context
                _context.Khareed.Add(khareed1);
            }

            // Save changes to the database
            _context.SaveChanges();

            // Redirect to the KhareedListView action with the id parameter
            return RedirectToAction("KhareedListView", new { id });
        }
        else
        {
            // If mainkareed already exists, set TempData["Error"] to 1
                TempData["Error"] = 1;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Handle any exceptions here
            // Log the exception, display an error message, etc.
            TempData["Error"] = ex.Message; // Example: Pass the exception message to TempData
        }
    
        // Redirect to SabtKhareedView action with the id parameter
        return RedirectToAction("SabtKhareedView", new { id });
    }
    ```
````

This refactored version includes the following improvements:

1. Used a `try-catch` block to catch any exceptions that may occur during the process and handle them appropriately.
2. Simplified the check for existing `mainkareed` using `FirstOrDefault`.
3. Combined the loop iteration and object creation for better readability.
4. Removed unnecessary calls to `ToList()` and optimized the code.
5. Added comments to explain the code's functionality.

Comment: Please use my code in the answer.Edit the answer

Answer (score 0):

Keep the table content existed, then per my knowledge, using ajax here would be a better solution.

Firstly, removing the `asp-controller="Home" asp-action="subData" method="post"` and `type="submit"` in the `form` element. Then we can add id for `tbody` and `button`. Adding click event handler and modify the controller api:

```
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Yare").val(@ViewBag.option1);
        $("#FaslName").val(@ViewBag.option2);
        $("#btn1").click(function(){
            alert(1);
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://localhost:7175/Home/subData",
                type:"post",
                data:{
                    "Yare": $("#Yare").val(),
                    "FaslName": $("#FaslName").val()
                },
                success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    $("#content1").empty();
                    $("#content1").append("<tr><td>hello</td><td>world</td></tr>")
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

//[HttpPost]
//public IActionResult subData(String Yare, String FaslName) {
//    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", new { Yare, FaslName });
//}

[HttpPost]
public string subData(String Yare, String FaslName)
{
      return "error";
}
```

============================================

In my humble opinion, what you want is that, users select an option in the selector, then submit the searching, and after returning the response, the selector can keep the option still selector. So here's my sample. When go back to the view, bring the selected option value and using js code to set the selected option.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="subData" method="post">
    <div class="d-flex">
        <label class="mt-2" style="margin-left:5px">سال</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="Yare" id="Yare" required autocomplete="off">
            <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="1400">1400</option>
            <option value="1401">1401</option>
            <option value="1402">1402</option>
            <option value="1403">1403</option>
            <option value="1404">1404</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class=" d-flex" style="margin-left:150px">
        <label label class="mt-2" style="margin-left:5px">فصل</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="FaslName" id="FaslName" required autocomplete="off">
            <option value="" default="" selected="">انتخاب کنید</option>
            <option value="1">option1</option>
            <option value="2">option2</option>
            <option value="3">option3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class=" text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-success  col-4 mb-2 " type="submit">ثبت اطلاعات</button>
    </div>
    <div>option1 : @ViewBag.option1</div>
    <div>option2 : @ViewBag.option2</div>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $("#Yare").val(@ViewBag.option1);
        $("#FaslName").val(@ViewBag.option2);
    </script>
}

public IActionResult Privacy(String Yare, String FaslName)
{
    ViewBag.option1 = Yare;
    ViewBag.option2 = FaslName;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult subData(String Yare, String FaslName) {
    return RedirectToAction("Privacy", new { Yare, FaslName });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But When go back to the view I want the inputs not to be empty.not selector.A list of inputs .Please look at the picture

Comment: Can I use View State? How do I use it in my case?

Comment: I have great respect for the unique cultures of each country but i really don't know your words in the picture. And if you try my code, you will see that, the first time you open the view,  the selector will have default empty value selected, but when you change the select then click submit button, then after the view load again, you will see the selectors still keep the options you select just now. Pls try my code sample in your project. Or do I misunderstand in some place?

Comment: My friend, just edit your answer for inputs, I don't want selectors

Comment: Don't forget I have a list of inputs

Comment: Your list is dynamically generated based on the searching result from the database, and it used the id as the query parameters. did you mean that, once the query result showed in the page, then next time with an incorrect parameter, you still want the last query result show in the page?

Comment: Yes, I want to display a warning if there is duplicate information in the database and not to empty the form

Comment: ok, then in my knowledge, you'd  better to use jquery ajax instead of form submit to handle the button click event, because form submit will lead to the page to reload so that you can't keep the data existed except you render the view with executing the last query again.